# Raspberry Pi 3 gets freezes after some days

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

I am using Raspberry Pi 3 Model B with 64GB SD card. Android Things OS is using with Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. After few days, it gets freeze.
I could not able to access my app which runs on it. All I want to do to get rid of frozen Pi, I switch off and On Raspberry Pi and all start working. But I do not know the reason. As this is frequently happening.
I AM NEW IN THIS.
Can anyone know the reason?

Comment: What voltage and amperage power supply are you using?

Comment: Is your app freezing, or is the whole OS freezing? What does your app do? Does the Raspberry Pi get too hot to touch after it runs for a long time?

Comment: Johnny Vegas- I am using 5V and 2.5 A power adapter .

Comment: EchoLynx- Yes, my raspberry pi gets too hot to touch. Whole OS gets freeze. My company deals with Vending Machine. For that we have designed an app to but a products.