# Debian server on raspberry pi becomes slow after about 30 hours

Tags: linux, memory, debian, performance

I am running about 5 docker containers on a raspberry pi 4b+ (4gb ram version), and about after 30 hours, it will become painfully slow to use, in all aspects. This server does not use a desktop environment, only SSH. But when it becomes slow, even SSH connections are incredibly slow, as well as every docker service being hosted, as well as its general network performance. I thought this was a RAM issue, so I added a swap space of 4GB. It seemed to help a little bit, but it still now has this issue where it slows down.  And the only other issue i could find that was similar to mine was this: *[Raspberry Pi 3 gets freezes after some days](https://superuser.com/questions/1463155/raspberry-pi-3-gets-freezes-after-some-days)*.

I am using the Argon40 EON NAS case with this, along with two 3.5" HDD drives. The power adapter i am using is the one that originally came with the case, and it is rated to support all versions of the Raspberry Pi 4b. My current solution around this problem is to create a cron job that restarts my server every day at 3am, however, this isn't really ideal. Any help, tips or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

EDIT:
Would like to clarify: as of 3 days of no restarting, the server seems fully operational like normal. i believe it was Jellyfin docker container eating up resources after a long period. i have turnt it off for now and everything seems fine... ClamAV however also likes to take a large amount of my Ram, too, so it could have been those two together using too much.

EDIT 2:
The server is now doing the same thing as it used to, with 9 days of complete uptime. Its acting VERY slow on FTP and docker too. Using htop, i can see nothing is using much CPU or RAM. they're both currently sitting between approximately 2% on all 4 cores and about 40%, going up and down every few seconds. Still not sure whats happening, a restart seems to speed everything back up to normal. Quite confused what is happening to be honest.

Comment: What dockers are you running? Seems at least one may be using up memory over time. Do any/all of those dockers use the HDD's extensively? How are the HDD's connected to the raspberry pi?

Comment: @Bravo, the containers i am running all write to the HDD's, but none of the containers are used extensively. i am running: Jellyfin, syncthing, filebrowser, vaultwarden in docker and openmediavault outside of docker. I also thought one could be using memory up over time, but if thats the case, im not sure how i would be able to tell which container is using up all my ram.

Comment: I believe webminstats has a resource graphing option.  It is very likely, that the VM are gradually using more RAM causing resource exhaustion.  Swap space is a factor of 100 or more time slower than RAM so using it will slow you down.  It would be less painful if you put your swap space on a SSD.  If some of your programs are leaking memory,then you have to report it to author of the program and hope they fix it.

Comment: Frankly, even with the 'better' versions, you're probably better off with a small form factor/NUC class machine over a raspberry pi